# Intellij Idea prompts "Unknown type Long" Grapqhl's configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, graphql

The IDEA say `"Unknown type Long"` in my configuration

I installed and uninstalled JS GraphQL but it was useless. I also tried to open it by txt,and change it.

```
schema {
    query: UserQuery
}
type UserQuery {
    user(id:Long) : User
}
type User {
    id:Long!
    name:String
    age:Int
    card:Card
}
```

I expect the result

```
query: {
    user(id: 100) {
        id,
        name,
        age,
        card {
            cardNumber,
            userId
        }
    }
} {
    data = {
        user = {
            id = 100,
            name = mansen: 100,
            age = 120,
            card = {
                cardNumber = 123456,
                userid = 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the actual output is

```
query:{user(id:100){id,name,age,card{cardNumber,userId}}} {
data = {
    user = null
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The IDE is right. There is no `Long` type in GraphQL schema spec.

Read [GraphQL Working Draft Schema Spec - Scalars Section](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/draft/#sec-Scalars).

There is already an open [issue to support a long type](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/73).
I guess, it will never be supported because [JavaScript cannot handle int64 types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/Int64).

If you really need an `int64` type, I suggest to use a string serialisation instead.

You could use something like the [json number format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-6).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! But "Long" is OK. You can browse my project " https://github.com/zhangchiyue/Graphql-demo". I rewrite my " RuntimeWiring" but
did not change  my code then  the project running success

Comment: `Long` is a java type and completely unknown in the JavaScript world where GraphQL comes from. More important, it's not mentioned in the GraphQL Schema Spec. 
The term `it runs on my machine` it not a prove

Comment: GraphQL is not bound to JavaScript in any way. In fact AppSync GraphQL implementation is mostly Java